# how to add a line of best fit to ggplot within a group with facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset comprising the following variables (fruit, prices, country, organic/non-organic, location).

I would like a plot like the one here but with one thing added - a line of best fit that runs through the points for each grouping of organic/non-organic, location, and fruit.

plot -> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3803117/stackoverflow.jpeg
[image]
For example, in the "Organic, City" square, I would like 4 lines of best fits - one centered on Apples, Bananas, Cherries, Dates, etc.

Here's the code I used to generate the plot.

```
p <- ggplot(data,aes(factor(fruit),price)) + 
  geom_violin(aes(fill=Country,trim=FALSE)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Country),position=position_dodge(0.9),width=.1) + 
  geom_jitter(alpha=0.5) + 
  facet_wrap(organic~location) +
  xlab("Fruit") +
  ylab("Price") +
  labs(fill="Country")
```

Here's a sample dataset if it might help -> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3803117/stackoverflow.csv

Thanks in advance so much for all the help!

Comment: Just trying to understand your question. Are you saying that, for example in the upper left facet, you want 4 lines of best fit that plot "price vs. country" for each of Apples, Bananas, Cherries, and Dates? If so, what does "price vs. country" mean? You could plot mean price in each country for each fruit. Would that do it?

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't the geom_abline documentation specify exactly what you are looking for? See the part "# Slopes and intercepts from linear model"

http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_abline.html

EDIT: Just checked and realized that there are no examples without the SE bands but you can easily disable them by setting SE=FALSE:

```
p <- qplot(wt, mpg, data = mtcars)
p <- p + geom_smooth(aes(group=cyl), method="lm", se=FALSE)
p <- p + facet_grid(cyl~.)
print(p)
```

If you provided a sample dataset it would be even easier to help you.

EDIT2:
The following might more closely resemble what the OP envisioned. however, I hasten that it is not meaningful as the ordering of country (or fruit, or type, or anything) can typically not be used to formulate a useful linear relationship:

```
p <- ggplot(data,aes(factor(country),price)) + 
  geom_violin(aes(fill=country,trim=FALSE)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=country),position=position_dodge(0.9),width=.1) + 
  geom_jitter(alpha=0.5) + 
  facet_wrap(organic~location+fruit) +
  xlab("Fruit") +
  ylab("Price") +
  labs(fill="country")
p <- p + geom_smooth(aes(group=1,color=country), method="lm", se=FALSE)
p
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added a sample dataset. One issue is that both of the variables in the example you gave are continuous, whereas for mine, I have a categorical variable on the x. Also, I think what I'm doing is slightly different because the variable I'm grouping on (group=) is different from the variable I'm using to facet_grid

Comment: So the facetting / grouping variable is not relevant as ggplot will apply the geom_smooth per facet --- I just did not have anything else at hand (good that you added the data set now).

However, the other point you raise points towards the problem jlhoward is asking: How can you formulate a trend without an x-variable. Ideally speak in terms of a liner regression, i.e. `reg <- lm(price ~ ?)`. To setup the reg-object (or a trend line) you need to name the independent variables that you expect to explain the price. A typical example would be time but your data misses time stamps.

Comment: I was hoping to use a dummy variable. For example USA = 0, France = 1, China = 2.

Comment: To reiterate @jlhoward's and my question - what kind of trend do you want to plot? Note that you are using jitter to plot the points as there is no x-structure to them - how could there ever be a meaningful trend? If you switched to geom_point instead of jitter this would become obvious with all points plotted in line.

If your only information are the categories country, organic, city and fruit than the only thing you can extract is the mean / mode / quantiles but not a trend.